# Manipulating a (very) long data file with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code which manipulates a very long document (more than a million lines).
In this text file there are certain timestamps at regular intervals (every 1003 lines) and in between
there is the data I need, which is a 1000 lines long and a header and two blank lines, which I do not need.

I want my code to take an input from the user between 1 and 1000 which refers to the timestamps and copy the corresponding chunk of lines into a separate txt.

The code I've written works as expected if the input is '0', but doesn't provide any output if it's any other number.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

time = input()

output = open('rho_output_t' + str(time), 'w',)

sys.stdout = output

filepath = 'rho.xg'

l = 2       #lower limit of 0th interval

u = 1001    #upper limit of 0th interval

step = 1003

with open(filepath) as fp:

    for t in range(0, 1000):

        print("{} ".format(t))  #this is only here so I can see the for loop running correctly

        for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):

            if int(time) == t and cnt >= l+(step*int(time)) and cnt <= u+(step*int(time)):

                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))


output.close()
```

Where did I mess up and how could I correct this?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: After the first iteration of your `enumerate` loop, the file contents are exhausted.  When your `for` loop runs the second time with `t=1` (and all subsequent times), the `enumerate` loop immediately terminates.

Comment: As above - you have 2 for loops, but really you only want to loop over the lines in the file once, so I'd only expect to see one for loop.

Comment: Small detail, if you do time = int(input()) will save you from writing and converting several int() :)

Comment: Imho you should post as an example a header section plus the first two or three rows of data of one block, so that we can see the structure of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for t in range(0, 1000):
        print("{} ".format(t))  #this is only here so I can see the for loop running correctly
        if int(time) == t:
            for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
                cnt >= l+(step*int(time)) and cnt <= u+(step*int(time)):
                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
```

This will make sure you only look at the content of fp when you're at the correct input time, preventing it from emptying out at `t==0`.

Comment: Have you tried running this? It definately doesn't do what you say, nor what OP wants.

Comment: It worked as expected for me. Thanks a lot for the help!! :)

Comment: @vferi Really? It's not even valid python.

Comment: @SpghttCd: it will go over all lines, cause `cnt` goes over all lines in the file. I think you're mixing up `t` and `cnt`.

Comment: @vferi: it would be faster to not iterate over all values of t and check instead `if int(time) in range(0,1000)`. For loops are notoriously slow i n python.

Comment: Ok, now I see how it could work and how it is probably meant. But still: the code you posted does not run and - as you mentioned yourself - the main structure with this nested loop is bad style.

Comment: Well Zephyrus (I believe, but I'm not 100% sure) missed an "if" from the beginning of the second to last line.
But I corrected that and it works as I expected.

@SphghttCD and ekhumoro
I don't know what you mean by this but I happily accept your explanation since I want to learn more as I'm a beginner. I'm sure the style is no good, but at this point I'm happy I even got it working.

Comment: Normally I think I would iterate through the file, checking each line for a certain header specific pattern and if it arrives at the header of choice, I'd switch a boolean variable to True and based on this info I'd process the next lines - until the next header sets the boolean back to False again. This has the advantage to be independent from having to know if each block _really_ is exactly of the same size. However, if you _are_ sure about that, I have probably sth for you, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
filepath = 'rho.xg'
l = 2       #lower limit of 0th interval
u = 1001    #upper limit of 0th interval
step = 1003

time = int(input())
start = l + time * step

with open(filepath) as fin, open('rho_output_t' + str(time), 'w') as fout:
    for _ in range(start):
        next(fin)
    for i in range(u-1):
        line = next(fin)
        print(f'Line {start+i}: {line}')
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Note that in case of your file structure is such that every block is not only of equal number of lines but also of equal number of bytes, you could even leave out the first loop and jump directly to the block of interest.

Comment: I have not even considered this, nor your other solution with the boolean tbh, since I was sure about the length.
This was the first script I've ever written (other than the usual practice whatevers). So I think I learned a lot, thanks for the help!